# Touch keyboard issue with Desktop mode of Windows8

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, activex, internet-explorer-10

We have very wierd issue with Windows 8. With desktop browser when we open any webpage and tap on any input textbox it doesn't pops up the keyboard and resize the browser. If I manually open the touch keyboard it just overlaps the textbox and what you type is actually hidden which makes it difficult for the user to know what they are typing..

Any solution to this would be highly appreciable.

Thanks
Vinod

Answer (score 0):

It's the normal behavior in desktop mode. Click on the icon next to the close icon on the upper right corner to make the browser re-size.

This question is better for superusers.